# Onclick change text in a link not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I'm trying to achieve on on the link click the text change to the second span; however this is not working.

**Script**

```
var reload = false;
$('#change').click(function() {
    reload = !reload;
    $('#change').click(function() {
    $('span',this).toggle();
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<li role="presentation" class="pull-right">
<a href="#" id="change">
<span>text 1</span><span style="display:none">text 2</span>
</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've complicated it with a flag and nested event handlers, just remove that and it works

```js
$('#change').click(function() {
    $('span', this).toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li role="presentation" class="pull-right">
        <a href="#" id="change">
            <span>text 1</span><span style="display:none">text 2</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

When you nest event handlers inside each other, you keep binding new event handlers on each click, and they keep counteracting each other, and it won't work as expected.
This is why you should generally never nest event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

```
<li role="presentation" class="pull-right">
  <a href="#" id="change">
    <span>text 1</span><span style="display:none">text 2</span>
  </a>
</li>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#change').click(function() {
  $('span').toggle();
});
</script>
```

but you don't really need jquery for this:

```
<li role="presentation" class="pull-right">
  <a href="#" id="change">
    <span>text 1</span>
    <span hidden>text 2</span>
  </a>
</li>

<script type="text/javascript">
function toggle () {
  document.getElementsByTagName('span').hidden = !document.getElementsByTagName('span').hidden;
}
document.getElementById('change').addEventListener('click', toggle);
</script>
```